# Select Button - CommandField on a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this below code  to create a GridView on a webpage.I am trying to disable the SelectButton or make it invisible, or just delete it.I tried

```
AutoGenerateSelectButton="false"
```

and

```
<asp:CommandField SelectText="Seç" Visible="false"
                                                                        ShowSelectButton="True"  />
```

I even deleted this part

```
<Columns>
          <asp:CommandField          SelectText="Seç"                                                                            ShowSelectButton="True" />
 </Columns>
```

None of them worked, the SelectButton is still there.
I tried to change it's `SelecText` to `Aç` with

```
<asp:CommandField SelectText="Aç"                                                                            ShowSelectButton="True" />
```

And this didn't work as well.I also tried

```
ShowSelectButton="False" and it didn't change anything.

   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelEnCokSatilanUrunler" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
                      <asp:Panel ID="PanelEnCokSatilanUrunler" runat="server" 
                      GroupingText="En Çok Satılan Ürünler" 
                      BorderWidth="1" Font-Bold="true">
                           <table class="style1">
                               <tr>
                                  <td>
                                      <asp:GridView ID="GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler" 
                                      runat="server"
                           OnRowDataBound="GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_RowDataBound"
                                       Font-Bold="false"
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                       AllowSorting="true"
                                     OnSorting="GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_Sorting">
                                            <Columns>
                                                 <asp:CommandField SelectText="Seç"
                                                     ShowSelectButton="True"/>  
                                            </Columns>         
                                  </asp:GridView>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
               </asp:Panel>

              </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is what I have in aspx.cs, which doesn't do anything with the `SelectButton`

```
protected void GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = "Ürün No";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text = "Ürün Adı";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text = "Satış Miktarı";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text = "Ürün Durum";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text = "Ürün Tipi";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text = "Marka";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text = "Model";                
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            if (EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortColumn == e.SortExpression)
            {
                if (EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortDirection)
                    EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortDirection = false;
                else if (!EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortDirection)
                    EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortDirection = true;
            }
            else
                EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortDirection = true;

            EnCokSatilanUrunlerSortColumn = e.SortExpression;

            EnCokSatilanUrunlerPageIndex = 0;

            GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler.SelectedIndex = -1;


        }

        void EnCokSatilanUrunlerGridDoldur()
        {
            GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler.DataSource = DAL.raporx.DAOUrunx.GetEnCokSatilanBesUrun(
                                                                                                    DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                                                                                    DateTime.Now
                                                                                                );

            GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler.DataBind();
        }
```

I just want a `GridView` without a `SelectButton`.

Comment: suggest adding a template field, and putting a link button which would say "Select"

Comment: @deostroll Thanks Mr.deostroll but I don't want the select button not even as a link button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as you don't need the `SelectButton` try to remove it from `Columns` section and remove `OnSelectedIndexChanged` from your `GridView` declaration and delete `GridView_EnCokSatilanUrunler_SelectedIndexChanged` method from code behind.

Comment: which version of Asp.net do you use?

Comment: I found out that the aspx class had a theme which makes all the grids have the same structure and changed it.Thank you for your help Mr.Mp.

Answer (score 2):

to remove select for a certain row :

in RowDatBound

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell the Gridview not to render the select button

```
gv.AutoGenerateSelectButton = false;
```

Next, add a template field. And add a link button inside it.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSelect" Command="cmdSelect" Text="Select" runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You need handler for gridview's RowDataBound event. You can do this in markup or code. I've shown how to do this via code:

```
gv.RowDataBound += new EventHandler(OnRowDataBound);
```

The event sink is define as follows:

```
void OnRowDataBound(object sender, RowDataBoundEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == RowType.Row)
    {
       LinkButton lbtnSelect = (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("lbtnSelect");
       //now hide or show as per you logic
    }
}
```

ps: Wrote code in haste, did not aim for correctness. Hence parts of code may be incorrect. If you google you might find the correct code for the above. Will edit later when I have time...

Comment: thank you Mr.deostroll, I found out that the aspx class had a theme which makes all the grids have the same structure and changed it.Thank you for your help, next time I will try your codes.