# window.focus() of JavaScript not working on IE9

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

This is my code

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DAL.DAOKullanici.Login(KullaniciTextBox.Text,SifreTextBox.Text))
        {
            VeriyazPROTicari.Sessionlar.Variables.loginkontrol = true;

            Session["kullaniciAdi"] = KullaniciTextBox.Text;
            Session["kullaniciId"] = DAL.DAOKullanici.GetEntity(DAL.DAOKullanici.KullaniciAdiIleKullaniciIdCek(KullaniciTextBox.Text)).ID;

            bool main_window_open = false;

            if (!main_window_open)
            {
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Main_Window", "<script>" +
                "var newwindow; " +
                "newwindow = window.open('" + "/dashboard/dashboard.aspx" + "', 'main_app_window', ' toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,left=1,top=1,scrollbars=" + "1" + ",resizable=1,width=" + "1280" + ",height=" + "800" + "'); " +
                "if (window.focus) " +
                "{newwindow.focus();} "
                + "</script>");

                main_window_open = true;


            }
            HataLabel.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            HataLabel.Text="Hatalı Giriş";
        }
    }
```

I have no problem with it except the JavaScript part.

What I am trying to is after `LoginButton` is clicked opening dashboard.aspx and setting focus on it.And this code opens dashboard.aspx and sets focus in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox 4.However,when I try it on IE9 dashboard.aspx is opened but focus does not work and dashboard.aspx remains under the login page.

How can I set focus on a new window on IE9?

Comment: Please do not edit in taglines or "Thank you (in advance)" type messages.

Comment: Because they are not accepted here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures - Thank you and similar endings are considered part of the signature.

Comment: This link does not mention Thank you etc. and what is there to not accept a thank you Mr.Karlsen?

Comment: This meta post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts - asks about thanks, and Jeff Atwood mentions that those are harder to detect, and elsewhere on meta there are discussions that state that if it isn't part of the question description, it shouldn't be there when it comes to openings and endings. So things like "Hi" and "Thanks", are not accepted.

Comment: Mr.Karlsen I know this post and you can see my answer at the bottom of that page, thank you for your interest but if `Stackoverflow is you` is true then I will keep writing thank you at the bottom of my question because this is the way I appreciate the community, and I will kep rollbacking any changes about it you can basically lock these posts just like an arrogant moderator did at this one [Select Button - CommandField on a GridView in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492629/select-button-commandfield-on-a-gridview-in-asp-net).Again thank you for you concern. @Lasse

Comment: Sorry, this is not open for debate and I'm not going to hunt for places to justify this, there are posts on meta regarding this. If you want to take it up as a serious debate, post to meta, other than that this discussion is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar problem to this and it seemed to happen because in IE9 (and any IE) that the focus() method is run before the window is rendered.

To get round this there are two ways that I can see that will fix this:

1. Set a timer to load the focus after a small amount of time.
2. Defer the JavaScript from being read until the window is fully rendered.

The timer method to me is not my preferred choice as in my personal opinion it is messy and if the page takes longer to load than the timer you are stuck with the same problem. To implement the timer you could use something like:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Main_Window", "<script>" +
    "setTimeout(function() { " +
    "var newwindow; " +
    "newwindow = window.open('" + "/dashboard/dashboard.aspx" + "', 'main_app_window', ' toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,left=1,top=1,scrollbars=" + "1" + ",resizable=1,width=" + "1280" + ",height=" + "800" + "'); " +
    "if (window.focus) " +
    "{newwindow.focus();} " +
    "}, 5);" +
    "</script>");
```

I have set a delay of 5 seconds, which may be overkill.

The defer method is my preferred choice as I feel it is cleaner and simpler, but it may or may not work:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Main_Window", "<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">" +
    "var newwindow; " +
    "newwindow = window.open('" + "/dashboard/dashboard.aspx" + "', 'main_app_window', ' toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,left=1,top=1,scrollbars=" + "1" + ",resizable=1,width=" + "1280" + ",height=" + "800" + "'); " +
    "if (window.focus) " +
    "{newwindow.focus();} "
    + "</script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

After what seemed like an eternity, my colleague figured out a way to make it work for us.

There are other references to the issue itself, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/a250c431-9f09-441c-9b78-af067233ed78 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979954

That said, we simply put the window.focus() in the body tag of the new (pop-up) page.

```
<body onload="FocusWindow()">
```

Defined FocusWindow() in a separate .js file as follows,

```
function FocusWindow() {
    window.focus();
}
```